# How much and why may a windows domain controller affect performance of sql-server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I assume a state-of-the-art installation therefore nothing weird like DC and SQL-Server on the same machine. Think about an installation following the commendations of microsft and all the recommended settings on both servers in a windows 2008R2 domain with sql2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, SQL Server should run on a dedicated server - no IIS, no DC, no other apps! This is primarily for security and performance reasons - memory, and disc IO particularly - but it also makes troubleshooting easier. 
If this is not about SQL Server Express, the licencing costs of SQL Server surely justify a dedicated box.

In clustered SQL Server environments, the installer prohibits SQL Server being installed on a box that is a DC.

See also:
http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/domain_controller_performance_p1.aspx